# Why is it assumed that these angles are 90 degrees?

Tags: vectors

It seems like it is assumed that these angles will always be 90 degrees but if this is true then why do u and v make perfect sides of a right triangle every time? Is this just a coincidence or is there a reason?

[image: An Image]

Comment: This appears to be a physics problem and not a math problem.

Comment: One in the same at times.

Comment: Because they're vectors...

Comment: I just can't see why if something is sitting on an incline the weight and force necessary to keep it from sliding would always make a 90 degree angle.

Comment: At times, yes.  At this time, no.  $v$ should probably be pointing in the opposite direction, representing the force of the ramp pushing on the object.  The resultant force has to be parallel to the ramp to keep the object on the surface of the ramp.

Comment: Because the forces act in an angle. We break them into components to make it easier for us to calculate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an inclined plane problem, the weight force on the mass is defined as acting "vertically downward".  However, the forces that influence the motion of the mass acts along the surface of the plane, and perpendicularly to that surface.

The acceleration of the mass along the surface is the resultant of the component of the weight or gravity force and any frictional force, both acting along the surface.  The frictional force is modeled as being a multiple (the coefficient of friction) of the "normal" force, which is the component of the weight force which is perpendicular to the surface.

So it is useful in this physical model to "resolve" the weight force ( $ \ \vec{w} \ $ in this diagram) into the so-called "parallel" ( $ \ \vec{u} \ $ ) and "perpendicular" ( $ \ \vec{v} \ $ ) components.

Comment: Great explanation, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

$u$ and $v$ are the projections of $w$ in the directions parallel and perpendicular to the indicated line. By definition, they are perpendicular--the angle between them is a right angle (assuming neither projection is $0$).

Another way to see this is to realize that $w$ is the diagonal of a unique rectangle, and the angles in a rectangle are all right angles.

Comment: So the forces just so happen to make these perfect right angles??

Comment: It is an aspect of the physical model and the choice of perpendicular components is intentional.

Comment: @KingSquirrel No they don't make perfect angles. We break them into components. Vector $v$ is the vertical component of vector $w$ (with respect to the ramp).

Comment: Ok I think I get it guys, thanks!